# Running javascript methods programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a webpage which has a javascript method in the following format:

```
window.usePlainText = function() {
    bla bla
}
```

A button on that same page calls the function using:

```
onlick = "return usePlainText();"
```

Here is how I tried to run it, but It did nothing:

```
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("usePlainText()");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InvokeScript()` takes a function *name*:

```
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("usePlainText");
```

Comment: Thanks! On another site it had the "()" too! Guess that's where it got stuck in my head!